# Avoiding unnecessary calculations of a set of names in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, permutation, python-itertools

I am working in a code in which I see who is online.

In this version, I chech who is conected in a group in which a concrete person is present.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it
from itertools import combinations

data = {
    'User': ['Seth','Abraham','Marius','Esther','Jonh', 'Ann', 'Alex', 'Jonh', 'Alex', 'Ann', 'Beatrix'],
    'InitialTime': ['01/01/2023  00:00:00','01/01/2023  00:00:00','01/01/2023  00:00:00','01/01/2023  00:00:00','01/01/2023  00:00:00', '01/01/2023  00:00:05', '01/01/2023  00:00:07', '01/01/2023  00:00:12', '01/01/2023  00:00:14', '01/01/2023  00:00:15', '01/01/2023  00:00:16'],
    'FinalTime': ['01/01/2023  00:10:00','01/01/2023  00:10:00','01/01/2023  00:10:00','01/01/2023  00:10:00','01/01/2023  00:00:10', '01/01/2023  00:00:12', '01/01/2023  00:00:12','01/01/2023  00:00:16', '01/01/2023  00:00:16', '01/01/2023  00:00:17', '01/01/2023  00:00:17']
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df.to_excel('df_5_personas.xlsx', index=False)

def calculate_overlapped_time(df, users_of_interest):
    df['InitialTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['InitialTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    df['FinalTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FinalTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

    overlapped_time = {}

    for [i, row_i], [j, row_j], [k, row_k] , [l, row_l], [m, row_m] in it.combinations(df.iterrows(), 5):
        if not (row_i['User']== users_of_interest or row_j['User']== users_of_interest or row_k['User']== users_of_interest or row_l['User']== users_of_interest or row_m['User']== users_of_interest):
            continue
        initial_time = max(row_i['InitialTime'], row_j['InitialTime'], row_k['InitialTime'], row_l['InitialTime'], row_m['InitialTime'])
        final_time = min(row_i['FinalTime'], row_j['FinalTime'], row_k['FinalTime'], row_l['FinalTime'], row_m['FinalTime'])
        superposicion = max(0, (final_time - initial_time).total_seconds())

        if superposicion > 0:
            key = f"{row_i['User']}-{row_j['User']}-{row_k['User']}-{row_l['User']}-{row_m['User']}"
            if key not in overlapped_time:
                overlapped_time[key] = 0
            overlapped_time[key] += superposicion

    results = pd.DataFrame(list(overlapped_time.items()), columns=['Group', 'OverlappingTime'])
    results['OverlappingTime'] = results['OverlappingTime'].astype(int)

    return results



results_df = calculate_overlapped_time(df, 'Alex')
results_df['Group'] = results_df['Group'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted(x.split('-'))))
results_df = results_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Group').reset_index(drop=True)
print(results_df)
```

As you can see, I calculate all permutations of the groups in which "Alex" appears, including all permutations of the same group, and then I use

```
results_df['Group'] = results_df['Group'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted(x.split('-'))))
results_df = results_df.drop_duplicates(subset='Group').reset_index(drop=True)
```

To remove the repeated rows.

Is there a way for me to do this on a more efficient way? I mean, just create a single version of each group of five people